# How do i create the following shape container in Html and css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create some containers which have different dimension or shapes

I don't know how to do it in CSS

I have tried using transform: skew(some px, some px) or border-radius but didn't work as I wanted

can't put the image because there is a shadow effect before and after hover on the container

[how can I create this container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxCb6.png)

Comment: can you put in some code you have tried??

Comment: you want card shape ?

Comment: Yes the card shape

Comment: Code i tried
<style>
width: 600px;
    height: 360px;
    padding: 10px;
    transform: perspective( 700px ) rotateY( 10deg );
    background: #f9f9f9;
border-radius: 20px;
</style>
<div class="block"></div>


Issue is this css is giving a tilt shape from both above and bottom but i need from bottom only

Comment: don't repeat the same question by creating another account (https://stackoverflow.com/q/56790836/8620333) we will close it the same way. Edit your old question if you have code or more details

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please!! Edit your question and add your code there - Don't put it in the comments section!

Answer (score 0):

Solution - >

You can try transform perspective property and rotate slightly y direction on parent container...

```
transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(45deg);
```

Comment: You can also check on this link...https://codepen.io/Mak0619/pen/RzjXgm